# Specifying since_id w/o max_id for getUserTimeline in Spring Social Twitter

Tags: java, spring, twitter, spring-social, spring-social-twitter

D ear community,

according to Twitter's guidelines on working with timelines it's recommended an application's first request to collect a full timeline omits the `max_id` parameter (see https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/timelines#the-max-id-parameter).

Now assume I have already collected a user's timeline in the past and stored the tweets in my database. Upon revisiting a timeline to gather new tweets I should be able to specify `since_id` in the first request based on my existing data.

Unfortunately I can't figure out how to accomplish this using Spring Social Twitter and the methods contained in `TimelineOperations`. There are only methods available which accept *both* `since_id` and `max_id` or neither.

I tried passing `Long.MAX_VALUE` as `max_id` which causes a `org.springframework.social.InternalServerErrorException`
and passing `null` is not an option because the method's parameter is of type `long` instead of `Long`.

tl;dr: How can I request a timeline while specifying `since_id` *without* specifying `max_id` using Spring Social Twitter?

Answer (score 0):

Passing 0 in place of max_id should do the work.